# Python list comprehension, can it be used for reading multiple files?

Tags: python, file-io, list-comprehension, nested-loops, python-itertools

Here is my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
from optparse import OptionParser

op = OptionParser()
(options, files) = op.parse_args()
print options
print files
content = []
for line in fileinput.input(files):
    # print "reading from " + fileinput.filename()
    if (fileinput.isfirstline()):
        content.append([])
        # print "is reading from the first line"
    content[-1].append(line.rstrip())
```

As you can see I am reading all lines in all files and constructing a structure like this

```
[["contents", "file 1"], ["file 2; is one line"], ["file 3", "has", "3 lines in it"]]
```

As far as I can tell the `fileinput` does not let me split up based on lines and so I have resorted to calling `isfirstline()` on each line to see if I have progressed to the next file.

Is it the case that I cannot use list comprehensions to do this work elegantly? Since I seem to be limited to a single loop over all lines. Is there something smart I can do to get it to give me the files separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the case that I cannot use list comprehensions to do this work
>   elegantly? Since I seem to be limited to a single loop over all lines.

In general, you should resist the urge to put too much in a list comprehension.  It can make the code harder to read and debug.  That said, list comprehensions work great with [*itertools.chain*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#module-itertools), you can put multiple for-loops in one list comprehension, and you can even next list comprehensions.

So, many answers are possible.  Here are a couple of them:

```
[map(str.rstrip, f.readlines()) for f in files]

[[line.rstrip() for line in f] for f in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

unless I misunderstand your code, this should work if you want to split it by line-break:

```
content = [[final for final in line] for line in fileinput.input(files)]
```

Comment: Well input already splits it by line so "\n" only shows up at the end if at all (I chomp it using `rstrip()`)

Comment: ahh okay, so then if you use rstrip then this works perfectly! i'll edit it!

Comment: So this creates a single array of lines like this: `["contents", "file 1", "file 2; is one line", "file 3", "has", "3 lines in it"]` It is the flattened version of my desired output (it is the original reason for making my loop the way it is)

Comment: oh, I missed that in the question...you just need to add a nested for loop then. Fixed it.

Comment: Looks like this makes the `final` be just the characters.

Comment: that honestly doesn't make sense when I'm thinking about it, but try it now. I don't have a directory of sample files to test this out on